Mocha Unit Test Framework + TypeScript + ECMAScript Modules = `[ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`
Very simple. I have test/simple.ts:
import assert from 'assert';
import {it} from "node:test";

it('sample typescript test', () => {
    assert.equal(1 + 1, 2);
});

I have .mocharc.json. Now, my project is using ECMAScript modules and import; is require the correct option to set?
{
  "extension": ["ts"],
  "require": "ts-node/register"
}

When I run yarn run mocha, I get  Exception during run: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /path/mocha-test/test/simple.ts
fyi, I'm using the latest NodeJS 20.x with the following package.json:
{
  "type": "module",
  "packageManager": "yarn@4.2.2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.14.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.6",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0"
  }
}

